# Не закрывать базовый поток

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных

Можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы не вызывался `Dispose` при использовании оберток `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter`?

Т.е., допустим, я открыл файл, далее обернул его в `StreamReader`, прочитал данные, далее мне нужно записать данные, я закрываю ридер, и открываю райтер, при этом если я закрою ридер, то закроется поток который я в него передал.

Т.е. добиться что-то вроде такого:

```
using(FileStream clientStream = client.GetStream())
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(clientStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        List<string> clientRequestData = new List<string>();

        while (reader.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            clientRequestData.Add(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(clientStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("SomeData");
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Так может просто закрыть ридер позже? То есть писатель добавить как вложенный using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` есть конструкторы с параметром `leaveOpen`. Он делает то, что вам нужно.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_